# Failed to load late-bound plugin: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin

Tags: maven-2

We have our local Maven repository which was working fine till yesterday.

Today we are getting the following error while building any project.

```
Failed to load late-bound plugin: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin
```

We haven't change any settings. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say because you skipped the next line that prints the **Reason**. A typical output looks like:

```
[WARN] Failed to load plugin: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin. Adding to late-bound plugins list.
Reason: Failed to load plugin. Reason: The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
```

It would have been interesting to join this line to find a fix for the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it.

I had to delete the plugins folder on my local repository then Maven downloaded the plugins again.

It works fine now.

Comment: this is unfortunately something you have to do a lot when dealing with plugins. Probably some metadata file of some repository was corrupted

Sean